# how to open current directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, osx

so i was learning unix and in unix when you want t open the current directory you type: `open .` and then the current dir that you are in opens in graphical interface.

i switched to linux because it seems to be more popular, and when i enter `open .` this is the output:
`~. open .
Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console`

ps. im using ubuntu on mac

Comment: Open in *what* graphical interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For browing current directory, you could try to use : `xdg-open .` .

Answer (score 0):

If by "open" a folder do you mean to do it in graphical mode from the terminal, it depends on your installed file manager, I don't know which is installed in Ubuntu but with with Nautilus (the Gnome File Manager) you just do:

> nautilus .